# How can I populate empty cells with a specific value during an extract?

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

Using the `mongolite` package, I create a MongoDB connection and then extract some data:

```
con <- mongo(collection = col,
             db = "db",
             url = "someurl")

data <- con$find(
            query = '{"_created_at": { "$gte": { "$date": "2018-10-01T00:00:00Z" }, "$lte": { "$date": "2018-10-31T23:59:59Z" } } }',
            fields = '{}'
)
```

The resulting data frame looks something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to impute a specific value, say `0` or `"No data"`, into those areas where `NA` and/or `<NA>` appear on the fly / whilst pulling data from the MongoDB system?

The example I give is a toy example.

In the real world, I will be pulling vast amounts of data and thus being able to impute other values into empty cells would be significantly more efficient than processing an enormous data frame once it has finished being extracted.

Comment: Maybe `data[ is.na(data) ] <- "No data"`

Comment: df$customerName[df$customerName==NA| is.na(df$customerName)] = your_value.    It is an example for one column for whole data you can follow @zx8754 answer.

Comment: Thank you both, this is good but I should've specified that I would like to be able to do this during the data extract itself. I have updated my question accordingly. Is that possible?

Comment: Why not after extract? (Just curious)

Comment: @zx8754 The example I gave is a toy example; in the real world, I will be pulling vast volumes of data in one go and to be able to replace non-present values on the fly would be a much more efficient approach.

Comment: I have no experience of MongoDB but I think writing an extra line of code is not a bad option. Don't worry about the vast volume of data. R is quite fast so you can give a try to it as well.

Comment: This question is more suitable to someone who knows mongodb well, or the [R package author](https://github.com/jeroen/mongolite)

Comment: @zx8754 I agree. I have e-mailed the author directly and asked, but have also pointed him towards this question - hopefully his answer can help other people, too.

Comment: @girijesh96 Yes, R is indeed one of the fastest tools out there which is one of the main reasons I have been using it for several years; however, this question is posed from more of an efficiency perspective, so I would like to make the whole process as streamlined as possible in order to give me a ready-to-go data frame that requires as little manipulation as possible once it has been extracted.

Answer (score 1):

If you have large data that you want to manipulate on the fly, you can either specify a custom `handler` function in the `mongo$find()` method, or you can use an [mongolite iterator](https://jeroen.github.io/mongolite/query-data.html#iterating) to read individual records so you can process them completely as you like.

Comment: I see. So assuming I iterate through each record individually, how would I replace `NA`/`<NA>` values during the process?

Comment: I built an iterator but the result that came in was a list (as detailed here: https://jeroen.github.io/mongolite/query-data.html#iterating) - is there a way to get a flattened result from it?